# How to check v-model object value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I'm vue newbie. I use vue ^2.6.10, and element-ui ^2.12.0. This is my api response data:

**API RESULT**

```
[
    {
        name: 'Test',
        age: 18,
        cash: null,
    },
    {
        name: 'Test2',
        age: 28,
        cash: 1004,
    }
]
```

And this is my table

```
<el-row class="el-row-margin">
    <el-table
    :data="personalData"
    border
    >

        <el-table-column
            v-slot="scope"
            fixed
            :label="$t('cash')"
        >
            <el-input v-model="scope.cash" /> <!-- How could I show cash as 0, when this value is nul -->
        </el-table-column>
    </el-table>
</el-row>
```

How could I to check the `scope.cash` is null will show 0. Thanks your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `value` and `@input` like this:

```
<el-input :value="scope.cash | formatValue" @input="scope.cash= $event"></el-input>
```

Of course you have to write your own filter as described before:

```
filters: {
  formatValue: formatValue (data) {
    return data 
      ? data
      : 0
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the element with `<el-input v-model="{{ scope.cash | formatValue }}" />`

Place this in the script tag above `data`

```
filters: {
  formatValue: formatValue (data) {
    return data?data:0
  }
},
```

You can use this filter for as many as key `formatValue`

Comment: 2.6.10 not support v-model with filter